# How to get applications process name c#

Tags: c#, winforms, process

I have winforms application that has execute and restart application function(.exe application) and successfully got the process name of my application process name by using:

```
var myApp = "C:\myApp.exe");
var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName(myApp.ToUpper().Replace(".EXE", ""));
```

However when I tried to execute other application like vlc media player. I can't get its process name.

```
var myApp = "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe");
var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName(myApp.ToUpper().Replace(".EXE", ""));
```

I found out that the executable file name is different on its name at task manager process name:

[image]

What is the right way to get my application process name? As I will use its name to kill the process by name.

Comment: What will you *do* with this application name? Task Manager uses various heuristics in places, here I think it's using the title from a top-level window owned by a process as "the" name of the process.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I will use it kill the process by its name

Comment: Right, so as I said, Task Manager is using the title of a window that the process opened. There's no "standard" way to get from an executable file to finding out that name unless you simulate *executing* the program and observe the windows that it opens.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, is there other way? as I'm trying to execute a dynamic applications by using my app.config file and kill its process when the exit or close button is clicked.

Comment: So you launch applications and then when you exit, you want to take down everything you've launched? If so, you may be looking for [Job Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/job-objects). Note that there *are* ways for processes to escape the job object by explicitly choosing to do so but most normal programs will not, and this may have to be "good enough".

Comment: @Richard You can try `Application.Exit()` or `Environment.Exit(0)` in `form_closing()` event. That would usually kill the process.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you name the process at creation if you wouldn't be able to kill it by that name.

If you define it, you could have control over its inevitable fate:

```
ProcessStartInfo myAppStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"myApp.exe");
Process myApp = Process.Start(myAppStartInfo);
```

...

```
try { myApp.Kill(); } catch { MessageBox.Show("It no die, dammit!"); }
```